# How to create a coherent object with java faker

Tags: java, faker

I'm trying to create an object `user` with java faker, and the variables are not coherent (if I create a user's name it could be `bob` and a username could be `jhon.smith`)

This is my code that creates a fake user:

```
public static User userRandom() {

    User p = new User();
    Faker faker = new Faker(new Locale("ES"));

    int ramdomN = faker.number().numberBetween(0, 1);
    char sex;
    if (ramdomN == 0) {
        sex = 'M';
    } else {
        sex = 'F';
    }

    faker.name().fullName();
    p.setEmail(faker.name().username() + "@lucatinder.org");
    p.setAge(faker.number().numberBetween(18, 90));
    p.setGender(sex);
    p.setName(faker.name().fullName());
    p.setPassword(faker.lorem().characters(8, 16));

    return p;
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
email: Elisa@lucatinder.org,
Password: gki5ra4l2v,
name: Elisa Robledo Robledo,
age: 33,
Gender: F, (Female)
```

But the actual output is:

```
Email: Elisa@lucatinder.org,
Password: gki5ra4l2v,
name: Carlota Robledo Robledo,
age: 33,
Gender: M, (male)
```

And that is wrong, because in `email` and `name` I have different names and Elisa is female but the `gender` is male

Comment: You're determining the sex based on what appears to be a random number generator, so ofcourse that's not going to match their name perse

Comment: On what assumptions is your expected output based? Your user is generated with random values.

Comment: you can use ```faker.demographic().sex()``` for the gender

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your code is that each call of `faker.name().fullName()` will generate a new name. (Also `faker.name().username()` has no relation to any previously generated full name.)

You could change your code to this:
(Assuming that each `fullName` consist of at least two parts, seperated by a space)

```
String fullName = faker.name().fullName();
String firstName = fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(' '));

p.setEmail(firstName + "@lucatinder.org");
p.setAge(faker.number().numberBetween(18, 90));
p.setGender(sex);
p.setName(fullName);
p.setPassword(faker.lorem().characters(8, 16));
```

However that won't solve your `gender` issue, as that does not seem to be a supported feature.
 Check this related [`issue`](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/issues/31) on the github project.

For whatever you're trying to do with that generated data, there (normally) shouldn't be an issue if the sex does not match to the name.

Comment: In the program I am using the JavaFaker class in, I also populate a "fullName" property, but due to the randomness of how the class works, I am generating names separately, and then concatenating them together for a full name.  This works well for providing controlled consistency, but also prevents the random titles and name suffixes from being included as they are unimportant to me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Faker documentation](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/), it appears you are getting a different name each time you invoke `.name()`.

> Each call to method fake.name() yields a different (random) result. This is because faker forwards faker.Generator.method_name() calls to faker.Generator.format(method_name).

Comment: As far as I've seen in the code `name()` only forwards to the matching generator. The method call after that generates a new something. Also you're link does not point to a `java` version of said library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm running into the same issue as well.  And it is by design.  The purpose of the JavaFaker class (based originally on a Gem from the Ruby language) is to kick back random data that matches the entity type... not have a coherent set of data for a given entity.

What is needed is a way of kicking back a base entity (such as a Name object, or an Address object), and then converting the data contained within into an instance object of some kind.  But based on how the JavaFaker class was written, I don't think trying to capture a single entity set is the intended use.  I'm not even certain that the data being returned in an address is associated in anyway... I think each entity/data property from the JavaFaker class is isolated from each other.  You can create base objects, but the JavaFaker class still "randomly" generates values for each sub property.